# Bootstrap modal only showing backdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**EDIT:** I've found the issue.  Turns out the person who originally made this page missed a closing `<div>` tag on modal s/he had created, so the content of my modal was hidden inside the original.

My bootstrap modal is not showing the dialog box, instead only showing the darkened backdrop. I have the following Modal set up in the footer of my page.

```
<div id="timePopup" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style='border-radius:0px;width:430px;margin-left:-215px'>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; top: 3px; right: 7px; z-index: 9999;">&times;</button>
        <div class="modal-body" style='border: black solid 2px;margin: 5px;'>
            <?php echo $popup_content; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$popup_content` just contains the simple string 'Test test test test'.  It is triggered by an `onclick` attribute in a `<span>` which call this function

```
function forcePopUp(){
    jQuery('#timePopup').modal('show');
}
```

The exact same code worked on our development server, but since moving it to the testserver this has started happening, or not happening i suppose.

From another post on SO I tried removing the .hide class from the modal, and have ensured this modal has a unique id. Any other ideas why would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you check errors in the console of your browser ?

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: No errors in the console.  In fact using the console I can see the classes change on the modal when the modal is triggered.  Bootstrap v2.3.2

Comment: The *Edit* solved my issue - I was missing a `</div>`

Answer (score 5):

If the modal html is rendered into a hidden area of the page, it won't display either

Comment: double and triple check the ID of the DIV of the modal you are trying to display - probably you have an error there

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(function(){
 $('.selector').click(function() {
   $('#timePopup').modal('show');
 });
});
```

Where .selector refers to a class or id in your span element.

Comment: Same result.  The issue is not with triggering the modal, that the modal itself is not showing.  The event is triggering because the backdrop shows.

Comment: Okay, so it's most likely some style issue. How about testing with a positive `margin-left` and/or some other styles? For border you could use e.g. `border:2px solid black;` Good luck!

Comment: my problem was ``('show')``ing the div that wraps my modal instead of the div with ``class="modal..."`` - this reminded me that I did this before. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the container style property

```
z-index: 10
```

go up as long as it's hidden
experiment which container should have this

Answer (score 1):

May be it's an old question. I faded it today and these are my cases of this error:

1/ CSS conflict
Try to remove some strange css link in your page when debugging and view the result, some CSS library not working with Bootstrap together

2/ Error in ajax posting, the data never return
If in your code have something like

```
$(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCarts", "Cart")',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var result = data;
                        $('#myCart').html(result);
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    fail: function () {
                        alert("Error with ajax");
                    }
                });
            });
```

And you cannot alert the data, that is code-side error, not an design-side error

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="timePopup" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style='border-radius:0px;width:430px;margin-left:-215px'>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; top: 3px; right: 7px; z-index: 9999;">&times;</button>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style='border: black solid 2px;margin: 5px;'>
        <?php echo $popup_content; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#timePopup">Open Small Modal</button>
```

if you remove inline css the model will come on middle demo link 
https://jsfiddle.net/kingtaherkings/fcnLqyhf/2/

Answer (score 1):

I just removed some of the CSS on the Elements and replaced the jQuery Function.

```
$(".modal-btn").click( function(){
  $("#timePopup").toggle(300);
});
```

Also the data-dismiss is not necessary here, since you can handle it all in jQuery with `.toggle() .hide() .show()`.

> [Here is the Pen](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/EEwEjM)

Answer (score 1):

For posterity and anyone else doing work on old code, my root cause was simpler and had nothing to do with Bootstrap.  The symptoms were the same (backdrop showing but no content).  I simply had a missing  tag.  Once I stripped out all the modal-body content and began adding each  back 1-by-1, the error was revealed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when calling a mal-formed URL. I was missing the action at the end:

```
$('#campaign-bulk-create').load( DD.baseDir + '/my-controller').modal('show');
```

Should have been:

```
$('#campaign-bulk-create').load( DD.baseDir + '/my-controller/my-action').modal('show');
```

This was not immediately apparent because the modal doesn't try to request it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a namespace collision between your modal and another element (identical `id` attributes, or however your modal selects its content), and the conflicting element is higher in the DOM, triggering the modal will make the modal backdrop appear but your modal won't be selected to be shown. Instead, JS will find the first matching element, which in this case is the conflicting element. The solution is of course to rename one of your elements.