# Bootstrap modal is not showing but the backdrop appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a code that calls a modal at javascript when a certain condition is met. Now my problem is even if the condition was met, the modal wont appear but the backdrop shows. Here`s the code for my js.

```
if(ExpiredSessionChecker($cookies)){
    console.log("Session has Expired!");
    if ($rootScope.IsForceLogout == 0) {
        $rootScope.IsForceLogout = 1;
        $rootScope.logoutMessage = "Session Expired! Please login again.";
        $('#forcelogout-modal').modal('show');
    }
}else{
    console.log("Session is OK!");
}
```

And here`s the modal

```
<div ng-controller="MenuController" id="forcelogout-modal" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <!--SUCCESS-->
                <div class="col-md-12  airtime-no-padding" style="background: #F0F0F0;">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                        <h4>{{ logoutMessage }}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="pull-right putCursor" ng-click="closeForceLogout()">OK</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the same codes for different condition and it works just fine. No idea why these codes wont.
I already read all threads here with the same title but it didn`t help.

Comment: Try loading the modal manually by typing `$('#forcelogout-modal').modal('show');` in the developer console. Does it load?

Comment: It does. So what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know.. waiting for other to reply

Comment: Check the z-ndex css property for your modal popup.

Comment: The modal doesn`t appear so I can`t check its z-index during the event. My modal`s set z-index is 1050 since i`m using the modal class.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384652/bootstrap-modal-only-showing-backdrop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it! Seems like the multiple parallel calls are causing it. I placed the code to a function that was called multiple times during a single page load so if the condition was met, it will call the modal multiple times.

I placed the code to another function that is only called once per page load and now it`s working.